# Good way of communicating between multiple SQL databases using Entity-Framework Core/RabbitMQ and HTTP API's

Tags: entity-framework, api, .net-core, rabbitmq, structure

I have created an ASP.Net core 2.0 API application so that when a put request comes in it adds the request to a Que (rabbitMQ) and then writes it to the database when the request is received, this request can be received in multiple projects under my solution to write to the different databases using entity framework.

However thinking about it if i want to send data from 1 database to another using this method how does my SQL server actually call these API methods with the json data wanted to be added to another database.

Is this idea completely wrong?
Should it be done another way?

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to send data from 1 database to another using this method how does my SQL server actually call these API methods with the json data wanted to be added to another database.

The simplest pattern is to add a simple table to each database to serve as an "outgoing queue" having a JSON message_body column, and any message metadata you want. Then have app services poll and do a "destructive read" on these tables, forwarding the data to the appropriate queue.

eg

```
create table outgoing_queue(id bigint identity primary key, message_type varchar(200), message_body nvarchar(max))
go


declare @msg nvarchar(max) = (select * from sys.objects for json auto)

insert into outgoing_queue(message_type,message_body)
values ('message type a', @msg)

go 10 ;


--from the app tier
with q as
(
  select top 1 *
  from outgoing_queue 
  order by id 
)
delete from q
output deleted.*
```